# pass huge data from database layer to presentation layer

Tags: c#, architecture, datatable, sqldatareader

I have three layer application in which all database related operation are performed in database layer.

for some queries huge data is fetch in sqldatareader (around 10 Millions rows with 32 columns), my question is how i can pass this big data to presentation layer where i am generating some reports.

after analyzing i have below options please share your inputs on the same.

1. Pass sqlDatareader itself

   - which is actually not the idea as i have to keep the connection open all the time.
2. use datatable

   - load sqldatareader into datatable and pass it as return statement. 
     this sounds good but i am not sure that this is the proper approach, in this case i would like to know does it will affect overall performance of the application or not. ?
3. use list as custom object.

Its winform based application installed on single machine only and i am using .net framework 3.5

your inputs and feedback are greatly appreciated.

Comment: As an aside, what do you want to do with 10 million records in the presentation layer?

Comment: @Szymon please take a look at update question.

Answer (score 1):

Is it really necessary to pass so many data at one moment? Wouldn't be paging better? It would solve you many problems. Anyway, who wants to see 10 millions of data on a single page? Who would want to wait 5 minutes until the page is loaded with all the data?

If you have three-layer architecture, you would probably want to use some business objects instead of objects for direct communication with a database. Presentation layer should know nothing or very little about the database used. So in your db layer, take loaded data, store it in business objects and pass these objects to a presentation layer.

Comment: actually i am exporting this big stuff in some excel sheet with predefined format, please take a look at updated question.

Comment: Well, that does not change anything. So can still do data analysis with parts of data. Take a few thousand, do analysis, write results. Is this possible or do you really, and I mean REALLY, need to load all the data at once?

Answer (score 0):

** passing sqldatareader will cost you lots of network usage and its not at all recommended to keep the connection open for such long time.

** Using datatable is a preferable option but however it depends on what kind of operations you want to perform on this huge data. By default, datatable can hold up to 16,777,216 rows

out of these two, second one is more preferable and gives good performance

Comment: In that case, there are special classes designed to export data from database to excel with efficiency....may be you should try that....the best way is to export the data to .csv format and excel handles this format

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass an SQLDataReader or a DataTable on to another application layer, that will expose your DAL and DataBase model implementation and will damage the seperation of application layers.
That being said, SQLDataReader keeps an open connection to the DataBase. Therefore, you should read all the rows you need and close it as early as you can.
Designwise, you should represent the data using your own classes.
Anyway, are you sure you need that many rows in the presentation layer? sounds peculiar to me.